# Handling special characters and getting specific text in large HTML file using lxml and Python

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using Python in Google Colab for extract my YouTube video history and generate a DataFrame with the data obtained from the .html file - that contains the video history.

I'm using lxml for parsing the HTML data, but, I'm facing the following problems:

- The text obtained with lxml cannot decode the special characters - i.e. *`"á", "é", "í"`*, emojies, etc.  ***EDIT (17/03/2023):** I've set the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tag on the HTML file's content in order to solve this point, though, I'm open to alternatives for avoid edit the file.*
- I'm unable to get the date I've view the video. This text is inside a `div`, but, it doesn't have a clear or easy way to extract the date. The desired result for each `div` is to get the date - example: `10 feb 2023, 08:03:13 COT`, etc.

---

Here is the extract of the HTML content:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <p class="mdl-typography--title">
          YouTube

          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
        Has visto <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zj7kUzvqNBk">El BOCON que NINGUNEO a Chavez y fue HUMILLADO frente a 130 000 fanáticos | Chavez vs Haugen</a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCivSw2EdxpUfH7vJ21Ob7NA">El Rayo Deportivo</a>
        <br>
        10 feb 2023, 08:03:13 COT
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption">
        <b>Productos:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;YouTube

        <br>
        <b>¿Por qué se grabó esta actividad?</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;Se guardó esta actividad en tu cuenta de Google porque estaban habilitadas las siguientes opciones de configuración:&nbsp;Historial de reproducciones de YouTube.&nbsp;Puedes controlar estas opciones de configuración <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">aquí</a>.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <p class="mdl-typography--title">
          YouTube

          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
        Has visto <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VArBMOvwiNE">No hay legado más grande, que el que dura para siempre. #LEOGACY</a>
        <br>
        Visto a las 08:02

        <br>
        10 feb 2023, 08:02:40 COT
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption">
        <b>Productos:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;YouTube

        <br>
        <b>Detalles:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;De los anuncios de Google

        <br>
        <b>¿Por qué se grabó esta actividad?</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;Se guardó esta actividad en tu cuenta de Google porque estaban habilitadas las siguientes opciones de configuración:&nbsp;Actividad en la Web y en Aplicaciones,&nbsp;Historial de reproducciones de YouTube,&nbsp;Historial de búsquedas de YouTube.&nbsp;Puedes controlar estas opciones de configuración <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">aquí</a>.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <p class="mdl-typography--title">
          YouTube

          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
        Has visto <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLr8hPtyrIU">Noraver Gripa Fast - Descongestiona las vías respiratorias y elimina los demás síntomas de la gripa</a>
        <br>
        Visto a las 08:02

        <br>
        10 feb 2023, 08:02:02 COT
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption">
        <b>Productos:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;YouTube

        <br>
        <b>Detalles:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;De los anuncios de Google

        <br>
        <b>¿Por qué se grabó esta actividad?</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;Se guardó esta actividad en tu cuenta de Google porque estaban habilitadas las siguientes opciones de configuración:&nbsp;Actividad en la Web y en Aplicaciones,&nbsp;Historial de reproducciones de YouTube,&nbsp;Historial de búsquedas de YouTube.&nbsp;Puedes controlar estas opciones de configuración <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">aquí</a>.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="header-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <p class="mdl-typography--title">
          YouTube

          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">
        Has visto <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM9kkSFwmg0">Resident Evil 6 Mercenaries No Mercy Requiem for War 2757k Claire Redfield (Cowgirl) PC 1080p</a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqPkDBlhiVGe07S3CZOQGWA">Radical Dreamer</a>
        <br>
        10 feb 2023, 07:46:44 COT
      </div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1 mdl-typography--text-right"></div>
      <div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-typography--caption">
        <b>Productos:</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;YouTube

        <br>
        <b>¿Por qué se grabó esta actividad?</b>
        <br>
        &emsp;Se guardó esta actividad en tu cuenta de Google porque estaban habilitadas las siguientes opciones de configuración:&nbsp;Historial de reproducciones de YouTube.&nbsp;Puedes controlar estas opciones de configuración <a href="https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols">aquí</a>.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
[...]
```

---

This is the code I'm using:

```
from lxml import etree, html

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse("/content/historial de reproducciones.html", parser)

# Get the divs that contains the entry:
divs = tree.xpath("//div[@class='content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1']")

# Store the data here as JSON:
js_data = []

# Loop the divs with the data for extract the values:
# > URL of the video
# > Video title
# > URL of the channel
# > Channel title
# > Watched time: Date where I watched the said video.
# NOTE: In the takeout, there are removed/deleted videos that does not 
# retrieve any links - in this case, the data is a empty row in the dataframe.
# If the "watched_time" is obtained, that row instead will contain ONLY the "watched_time" value, and that's the desired output for those cases.
for ind, div in enumerate(divs):
  temp_links = div.xpath("a/@href")
  temp_links_texts = div.xpath("a")

  if (temp_links is not None):
  
    # Here, I've omitted certain code for fill the "temp_links_texts" - it's not the problem 
    # for get the "watched_time".
    video_link = temp_links[0]
    channel_link = temp_links[1]
    video_text = temp_links_texts[0].text
    channel_name = temp_links_texts[1].text

    # When I try to get the date,  I'm unable to get the desired text = 10 feb 2023, 08:03:13 COT. 
    # watched_time = "" # I only get the (Has visto ) text - instead of (10 feb 2023, 08:03:13 COT).
    
    # Append the data: 
    js_data.append({ 
        "Video" : video_text, #OK
        "Link": video_link, #OK
        "Channel": channel_name, 
        "URL": channel_link,
        "Watched" : watched_time
    })
    
    # Clear variables: 
    video_link = ""
    video_text = ""
    channel_link = ""
    channel_name = ""
    watched_time = ""
```

---

This is the actual results - *shortened for demostrative purposes*:

| index | Video | Link | Channel | URL | Watched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | El BOCON que NINGUNEO a Chavez y fue HUMILLADO frente a 130 000 fanáticos | Chavez vs Haugen | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zj7kUzvqNBk | El Rayo Deportivo | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCivSw2EdxpUfH7vJ21Ob7NA |  |
| 1 | No hay legado más grande, que el que dura para siempre. #LEOGACY | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VArBMOvwiNE | Gatorade Colombia | https://www.youtube.com/@gatoradecolombia9204 |  |
| 2 | Noraver Gripa Fast - Descongestiona las vías respiratorias y elimina los demás síntomas de la gripa | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLr8hPtyrIU | Noraver Colombia | https://www.youtube.com/@noravercolombia3979 |  |
| 3 | Resident Evil 6 Mercenaries No Mercy Requiem for War 2757k Claire Redfield (Cowgirl) PC 1080p | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM9kkSFwmg0 | Radical Dreamer | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqPkDBlhiVGe07S3CZOQGWA |  |
| 4 | Mega Retrospectiva: Los Simpson Hit & Run (Parte 4) | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh9p5fbUgY8 | Max Power | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ99bYEb57kXEIaSALrj_6A |  |
| 5 | Gana más con Cabify | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTwtHdKuozY | Cabify | https://www.youtube.com/@Cabifys |  |
| 6 | ESTOS DARKLORDS SI PEGAN DURO | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwahSkgYhYY | Duel Random L 2.0 | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkty7zBHmasLAwIBc9cgiCA |  |
| 7 | Office Space - fixed the glitch | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUE0PPQI3is | Peter Ghosh | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqNUlAWLXWLf9ZwTRGX6Xqw |  |
| 8 | Llegamos a más de 800 destinos y a millones de hogares en Colombia | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tq0LDrLZzEI | Homecenter Colombia | https://www.youtube.com/@homecentercolombia |  |
| 9 | Iron Man: Archivo de Monstruos | Mech Strike | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHa0rLQh4cE | Marvel HQ LA | https://www.youtube.com/@MarvelHQLA |  |
| 10 | Review Temporada 31: Esto no necesitaba dos partes | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUYebZN4Xv8 | Max Power | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ99bYEb57kXEIaSALrj_6A |  |
| 11 | Vuélvete Todo Claro y recibe más beneficios sin pagar más | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9pverB6qAU | Claro Colombia | https://www.youtube.com/@ClaroColombia |  |
| 12 | Atomic Heart = Russian Propaganda? | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzDCQzH1sO0 | Setarko | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcznKF2NAgexfaZtsOz7lFw |  |
| 13 | Mortal Kombat as an 80's Dark Fantasy Film | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gms5pD-EbMk | SON | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr0lGe_WRgMxXEQtmmEdsCA |  |
| 14 | Pirates of the Caribbean as an 80's Dark Fantasy Film | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2z36d5eiCcs | SON | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr0lGe_WRgMxXEQtmmEdsCA |  |
| 15 | What Happens When You Are a Coomer | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhXmO64ut4I | Lord Wojak | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCULzpwL5TRDydBF_bWfJjrw |  |
| 16 | Wagering our RAREST Yu-Gi-Oh Cards in a Duel! Rare Hunters 11 - Ancient Sanctuary | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x29ZRFdCpfE | Team APS | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaqlCjzSFmunjBOP4EmYpxg |  |
| 17 | Yu-Gi-Oh - 4,900 Attack Dark Paladin | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUHJIVvgkVc | GrandMasterKaiba | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLj6N6_WjY8upsjJVS9Osug |  |
| 18 | T̶E̵T̶R̸I̵S̷ B̶E̸A̶T̶B̸O̵X̵ [VOID] {2019} | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xQgxk4OyKI | TimTam60.mp5 | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsObTxoQ2g90OuxriztJyHg |  |
| 19 | Wojak's New Year New Me | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlShmY1XrDo | Wojak Life | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTi2tQgA_yu2uu_9RiyT2yA |  |
| 20 | Evils of Instant Gratification | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWQ3LH-DTvk | Wojak Life | https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTi2tQgA_yu2uu_9RiyT2yA |  |

With the information posted here, is there something missing? - how the mentioned issue can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewing dates are in the `tail` of the second `<br>` element within each `<div>`.

Demo (test.html contains the HTML in the question):

```py
from lxml import html

tree = html.parse("test.html") 
divs = tree.xpath("//div[@class='content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1']")

for div in divs:
    br_elems = div.xpath("br")
    print(br_elems[1].tail.strip())
```

Output:

```
10 feb 2023, 08:03:13 COT
10 feb 2023, 08:02:40 COT
10 feb 2023, 08:02:02 COT
10 feb 2023, 07:46:44 COT
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - I've changed the code for handle a case I didn't found before. In the takeout html file, there were cases when only a `<br/>` tag was found. So, I've added your solution, plus this modification: `try: watched_time = br_elems[1].tail.strip() except Exception as ex_watched_time: watched_time = br_elems[0].tail.strip()` - I can't [edit] your answer, but, I want to let you know your solution works and with my modification, the "unexpected case" was handled successfully.

Comment: Yes, my code is just a minimal demo based on only one small HTML sample, and without any error handling at all. I am happy that I could help!